# String Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, string, variables, initialization

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class empMod

{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int choice;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
        {
        choice = -1;
        System.out.println("Employee Data:");
        System.out.println("1. - Employee Name:");
        System.out.println("2. - Employee Hire Date:");
        System.out.println("3. - Employee Address:");
        System.out.println("4. - Employee Number:");
        System.out.println("5. - Exit");

        choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:

            String empName = new String ();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the employee:");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            break;

            case 2:

            String empDate = new String ();
            System.out.println("Enter the hire date of the employee:");
            String date = input.nextLine();
            break;

            case 3:

            String empAddress = new String ();
            System.out.println("Enter the address of the employee:");
            String address = input.nextLine();
            break;

            case 4:

            String empNumb = new String ();
            System.out.println("Enter the Employee number:");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            break;

            case 5:

            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.println("The name of the employee is: " + empName); // <-- This is the line where the error occurs.
            break;

            default:
            continue;
            }

        }
    while (choice != 6);
    } 
}
```

The intent of the program is to have the user input information about the employee, and then at request, have the information displayed. When I go to compile the program, I get the following error:

```
empMod.java:57: error: variable empName might not have been initialized
                                System.out.println("The name of the employee is:
 " + empName);

     ^
```

The string variable is initialized in another case though, so I am not sure of the problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So, if I have the code print out the information outside of the switch statement, will that work?

Answer (score 2):

The empName variable is only initialized in the `case 1` section. So what would happen if this block was never executed, and the `case 5` section was? What would be printed, since the variable has never been initialized to anything?

Add

```
String empName = "";
```

before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`switch (choice)` and `case`s later means, that according to value in `switch` (choice) one of `case` will be choosen. If it will be `5`, your variable will not be initialized.

you need to initialize `empName` before `switch`, of in every `case` in whitch it's used.

And you should not use `String empName = new String ();` but `String empName = "";`- it will use String Pool.

Comment: So, if I have the code print out the information outside of the switch statement, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` block contains a scope. Variables declared in that scope can only be used there. Think of the `switch` as multiple `if-else`s. If the `if` (the `case`) that initializes you variable doesn't get executed, then you are left with an uninitialized variable. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

In

```
case 5:
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("The name of the employee is: " + empName); // <-- This is the line where the error occurs.
    break;
```

`empName` is only initialized if execution flowed through all the cases (ie. `choice` had value 1 and your cases did not have breaks). But the compiler cannot be sure of this.

The way to fix this is to declare your `empName` variable outside the `switch` block so that its scope is method scope and not limited to inside the `switch`. You would need to initialize it to some default value so that the compiler knows that it is initialized.

```
String empName = "Not a Name";
```

Comment: It's not really a matter of scope. The variable is visible from the case 5 section, because it's in the same block as the case 1 section. But there is no guarantee it has been initialized.

Comment: @JBNizet Sure. It won't be initialized for certain because execution might not have passed through all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Because int `case 5`, you didn't define `String empName = new String ();`, you can define empName in main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int choice;
    String empName = "Not a name";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

...
```